# NestJS-Sequelize: InjectModel vs Predefined String Token

Tags: nestjs, sequelize-typescript

Trying to figure out the best approach.

1) Sequelize section in NestJS docs shows the following way:

```
const catsProviders = [
  {
    provide: 'CATS_REPOSITORY',
    useValue: Cat,
  }
```

And then in service

```
 @Inject('CATS_REPOSITORY') private readonly catsRepository: typeof Cat
```

2) And recently I found in Nest github Sequelize sample:

```
@InjectModel(User) private readonly userModel: typeof User,
```

Is there any difference - at least for Sequelize - in term of perfomance or memory usage?
The first approach is way more verbose: you also need to create a constants file for tokens.
But at least having a predefined token means that we use the same provider instance in different parts of application?
But maybe InjectModel does the same under the hood ?

Answer (score 2):

`@InjectModel()` is a wrapper around `@Inject(getModelToken())` which ends up returning a token like `connectionPrefixEntityRepository` (this is the same functionality as `@nestjs/typeorm`'s `@InjectRepository()` actually). So there is no performance difference between `@InjectModel(Entity)` and `@Inject(CONST_TOKEN)` as they are essentially the same.